# What the meaning of bolded part especially "except to"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> never give in, never give in, never, never, never, never-in nothing, great or small, large or petty — never give in **except to convictions of honour and good sense.**

—By Winston Churchill

**Conviction mean i think-A strong belief**

Comment: Is it perhaps the "to" that confuses you? It's related to "give in": you can "give in to something" (as in "accept or stop resisting against something"). So the statement is something like — and I'm going to use parentheses to now to group words together — "never give in, *except* when giving in to ((convictions of honour) & (good sense))"

Comment: @FilipMilovanović meaning of **give in to**?

Comment: @Sam **to** indicates what makes you give in, for example this: "The government cannot be seen as giving in **to terrorists' demands**."

Comment: @JavaLatte can you (please) paraphrase the sentence by Winston Churchill.

Comment: Give in only in circumstances where failing to give in would compromise your personal integrity or go against common sense.

Comment: @JavaLatte conviction means"belief" here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More often than not, to '*give in*' to something has a negative connotation - for example, to surrender in battle, to buckle under pressure etc. But, actually, it is pretty much exchangeable with words like '*yield*', and can be used positively.

Churchill's speech is talking about remaining steadfast - never 'giving in' to negative forces. However, he adds an *exception* that one can 'give in' or 'yield' to *positive forces* - namely honour and good sense. In other words, if honourable thoughts or good sense make you change your mind or actions, that is a good and noble force to 'give in' to.

Comment: "Conviction of honour" mean?— **strong belief about honour.**

Comment: @ Sam I believe means "convictions characterized by honor and good sense," but it could be interpreted either way.

Comment: @sam Have you looked at 'conviction' in the dictionary? It means a deeply-held belief or value. I didn't think that was the part of the sentence you were asking about.

Comment: @Astralbee yes, **conviction** is a part of the sentence.

Comment: @Sam Well, convictions, beliefs and feelings could be viewed as either negative or positive. One could "*give in to fear and doubt*", so equally one could 'give in' to positive feelings, too. It's a slightly unusual use of the expression but that's what makes it powerful.

Comment: @Astralbee "Conviction of honour" mean?— **strong belief about honour.**

Comment: @Sam Perhaps, but there could be a difference between convictions *about* honour and *honourable convictions*. I mean, you could believe in honour on principle but not enact it. For example, one might know or believe that smoking is bad for health, but carry on doing it anyway. That's why a conviction is deeper than a belief. It is a motivating force.